# utf-8 codec can t decode byte 0x93 in position 249 invalid start byte

Tags: python, chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatbot=ChatBot('corona bot')

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",

              "chatterbot.corpus.english.conversations" )

  

response = chatbot.get_response('What is your Number')

print(response)

response = chatbot.get_response('Who are you?')

print(response)
```

Comment: 0x93 is obviously an invalid start byte in UTF-8. Check the input byte stream, it isn't UTF-8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.